# How to not save error commands in history in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-web-developer, psreadline

Every command I enter are saved in history but I want not to save the command that are shown error in the shell.

what should i add in the powershell config to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Clear-History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/clear-history?view=powershell-7.3) cmdlet to remove entries from the history. Since history doesn't save results of the commands, you need to remove invalid ones manually.